# searching for a file name using only an extension

Tags: c, linux

prev problem was not described well.
I need to retrieve a file name and assign that name to a variable. The only thing is that the file can have any name.
The thing that I know is the file extension and there can only be one file of this extension.
Is there any way to implement this in C?

Update #1
File extension is `*.knb` and target is Linux system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define LOG_() do{fprintf(stdout, " UNIT TESTING...\n");}while(0)

char* knbname;

void fName(void);

int main()
{
     LOG_();
     fName(void);

     //do some more code 

return 0;
}

void fName(void){
     DIR           *d;
     struct dirent *dir;
     d = opendir(".");
     if (d)
     {
        //find file with *.knb extension and place name into knbname
     }
     closedir(d);
}
```

I don't know how to find for a `*.knb` file in the fName() function and how to assign name to `knbname`. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Add a `while( (dir = readdir(d)) != NULL )` loop and compare the value of `dir->d_name`. (Note that "dir" is probably not the best name for the `struct dirent`, since a directory entry is not necessarily a directory, and indeed you probably don't care about the directories, unless you want to do a recursive descent.)

Comment: In the loop suggested by @WilliamPursell you could then parse each directory entry name with `strtok()` (using '.' as delimiter) untill you find the wanted extension.

Comment: OT:  Don't line up your variables like that.  What happens if you have to change the type of the variable?  How about when it's multiple variables?  You'll waste a lot of time just getting them to line up again.  That's time spent doing nothing useful.

Comment: You could use POSIX [`nftw()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html)
to traverse the directory tree.  You could use [`fnmatch()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html)
to match the file name glob.

Comment: No need for even `strtok()` if you're looking for just a suffix, could just use `strcmp()` aimed at the tail part of the string at the correct position based on length.

Comment: regarding; `d = opendir(".");
     if (d)
     {
        //find file with *.knb extension and place name into knbname
     }
     closedir(d);`  Do not close the directory unless the call to `opendir()` was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reinventing POSIX's [`glob()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html). Here is an example of how to use it (see the flags in manpage for more options):

```
#include <glob.h>

int main(void)
{
    glob_t glob_res = { 0 };

    glob("*.knb", 0, NULL, &glob_res);
    if (glob_res.gl_pathc == 0) puts("No match.");
    else printf("First match is %s\n", glob_res.gl_pathv[0]);

    globfree(&glob_res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After Andrew pointed out some major flaw in the previous design, i will make another attempt for a solution...

```
int hasExtension(char *filename, char *extension);

int main(void)
{
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if(NULL == (directory = opendir(".")))
    {
        perror("Failed to open directory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while( NULL != (entry = readdir(directory)) )
    {
        if(DT_REG == entry->d_type) { // Regualar files only
            if(hasExtension(entry->d_name, ".knb"))
            {
                printf("Match     - %s\n", entry->d_name);
            } else {
                printf("No match  - %s\n", entry->d_name);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(directory);

    return 0;
}

int hasExtension(char *filename, char *extension)
{
    size_t filename_len, extension_len;

    if((NULL == filename) || (NULL ==extension))
        return 0;

    filename_len = strlen(filename);
    extension_len = strlen(extension);

    if(filename_len < extension_len)
        return 0;

    return !strcmp(filename + filename_len - extension_len, extension);
}
```

Comment: And if `filename` is `..` or `xxx`?

Comment: Andrew, yes now i see... you would move beyond the boundaries... :(
Bad idea...

Comment: Actual the hasExtension function should be refactored/renamed into a strEndsWith (string ends with), which is basically what it does and there by making the code more generic/reusable.