# How shell glob expansion works as in ls -l *?

Tags: bash, shell, system-calls, glob

How is shell expanding the '*' as in

> ls -l *

Is there any system calls happening behind the scene to read all the file in the directory ? I tried strace but not showing any system calls specific to globbing

Answer (score 4):

The glob is expanded by bash, not by `ls`. When you run `strace ls *` only the `ls` is traced, but the glob expands before `ls` or even `strace` runs so you won't see the system calls of it in the trace.

To trace the expansion of a glob use `strace bash -c 'echo *'`.   This will also include system calls from the shell startup. To show only the system calls done for `echo *` you can filter the results with ...

```
strace bash -c '[ -e startglob ]; echo *; [ -e endglob ]' 2>&1 |
sed -n '/"startglob"/,/"endglob"/p'
```

Comment: But if we do `strace bash -c 'echo *'` it trace bash right ? not *

Comment: `*` is not a command; it is the work of the shell (here bash) to expand `*`. However, with just `strace bash ...` you also get a lot of system calls for just starting up the shell. I edited my answer with a way to extract only the relevant part.

Comment: @Socowi The `sed` command may not work right if the underlying call is `stat32` or `stat64` -- using `sed -n '/stat.*("startglob/,/stat.*("endglob/p'` should work in any of these cases.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good catch. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Read [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). Globbing would use several [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html): [access(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html), [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) [opendir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) (which uses [getdents(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html)...) [closedir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html). See also [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html).

And [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) is (like [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/)) [**free software**](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), you can download its source code and study it, compile it and improve it.

You can use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand how GNU bash (or any other Linux application) works.

Of course, globbing is done by the shell (before [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)...), *not* by the `/bin/ls` process

Comment: Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch . I have tried strace to understand how its working and also read through the bash github . I have not seen much difference between ls -l and ls -l * . There was no opendir , readdir , getdents call . Is strace not capturing all glob expansion calls ?

Comment: Again, globbing is done by the shell. Not by `ls`

Answer (score 2):

> How is shell expanding the `*` as in `ls -l *`

When meeting a globing pattern like `*`, the shell reads all the directory entries and compare them one by one with the pattern.

A quick glance at the source code tells me this is probably done in [`glob.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/glob/glob.c), especially in the [`glob_vector()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/glob/glob.c?h=bash-5.1#n619) function.

> Is there any system calls happening behind the scene to read all the file in the directory ?

Of course, you cannot read the content of a directory without the help of the kernel.

That said, system calls are low-level, so don't expect to find any call to `opendir()` and `readdir()` which are libc calls. Rather, you will find calls to `open()` and `getdents()`/`getdents64()` instead.

> I tried strace but not showing any system calls specific to globbing

`strace` is NOT the right tool for that. This is not your kernel that is doing globing, this is your shell, possibly with the help of libc functions, therefore there is no system call involved (except from the above-mentioned low-level calls to read the directory content).

If you want to trace calls to library functions like `opendir()`, `readdir()`, `glob()`, `strcmp()`,... you MUST use [`ltrace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html):

```
ltrace bash -c 'ls *'
```

That said, Bash has its own globing system, more advanced than the basic one specified by the POSIX standard, so it won't rely on library functions like [`glob()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html) or [`fnmatch()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html). Don't expect to see calls to them in `ltrace` output.

If your aim is to use globbing in your own application and study how it is done, you may want to have a look at `glob()` which is simpler than Bash's globbing (FYI, I recently posted an example of use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66324041/7233423)).